# how to make a physics based click and drag/throw in unity2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

how could i make a click and drag script work the way, that if I have an object which is a rectangle and it has gravity and I grab it from the bottom and drag it up somewhere where's no collider, it would flip itself using the gravity. Sort of like "pinning" the object and rising/ moving it how the cursor moves. So if you were to spin the cursor the rectangle would spin due to G forces with rigidbody.
Or if that's not explainable I'd like to know how I could make tossing possible. Like when I do a quick swipe to left and release the mouse, the object would go flying in that direction.
i want to make it like people playground where it has gravity and works the way i explained it.
if its possible please tell me. i can show you the code i have so far if you need it.
code so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Drag : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 difference = Vector2.zero;

    private void OnMouseDown()
{
    difference = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - (Vector2)transform.position;
}

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        transform.position = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - difference;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the rectangle Rigidbody2D to a "Mouse" Rigidbody2D using [Distance Joint 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-DistanceJoint2D.html). Have the mouse Rigidbody2D always be at the position where the mouse is, and as long as you press the button, attach the rectangle Rigidbody2D to the mouse Rigidbody2D.

Comment: wow thank you! i'll try this and report back

Comment: just asking what do you mean by a "mouse" rigidbody?? how would i do that

Comment: create a new rigidbody2D and attach a script to it that always puts it at the position where the mouse is with `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`.